# Вывод строк и массивов, сравнение

Tags: c++

Почему строки типа char можно выводить командой

`cout << str;`

а массив нельзя (т.е. нужно выводить каждый элемент массива отдельно). Разве строки это не массив символов?

Comment: Потому что у массивов нет перегруженного оператора <<.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У оператора вывода в поток `operator<<` [есть соответсвующая перегрузка](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), которая принимает `const char*` для вывода нуль-терминированной строки. Массив символов неявно преобразуется к данному типу. Нуль-терминированные строки - это давно устоявшийся тип из языка Си.

Для обычных массивов (не символьных) перегрузки, которая принимает указатель на тип - нет. Потому что никто не знает как такие массивы надо выводить, какой разделитель добавлять, например, между элементами и где будет конец такого массива.

Comment: Думается мне, что основная причина - по указателю на массив нельзя понять где он заканчивается (в отличие от нуль-терминированных строк). Можно конечно перегрузить оператор `<<` чтобы он принимал какой-нибудь `array_type (&arr)[N]`, но это же на каждый размер масива будет своя функция - как-то не очень хорошо... А разделитель между элементами, так это просто можно было бы добавить очередной фасет в `locale`, чтобы он определял и и разделитель, и вид скобочек вокруг массива...

Comment: Хотя для `>>` есть перегрузка принимающая [массивы](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2). Возможно вывод массивов просто никому не нужен...